# Converting first edition supplements to Feng Shui 2?

Tags: conversion, feng-shui

I've decided to pick up Feng Shui 2 again after a long absence.  I have a lot of the supplements for the original version, which I'd like to utilize in a new campaign with the more recent ruleset.  Is there a good schema to update these old supplements?  Or is one even needed?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62791/44723